How can I create a kaleidoscopic filter in AE
I want to know how to replicate a kaleidoscopic filter (like in the prism lens fx look in the attached figure below) for a project I'm working on...

What is the workflow / technique to create this?

Start with CC HexTile. Set Render to 'Tile' and Radius to around 370 (assuming HD comp). Add a feathered circular matte to the center and place your original media behind this.
This is the fastest way to do it but the joins won't be feathered.
For this, you would need to manually create eight instances of the media (masked and feathered) and position them around in a circle.
